# Aggregate dataframe based on 2 categorical columns and value of 1 python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

with the following sample:

```
Offer Client amount

'Off1' 'C1'  1000
'Off1' 'C1'  10
'Off1' 'C2'  2222
'Off1' 'C3'  0
'Off1' 'C3'  10
'Off2' 'C4'  11
'Off2' 'C1'  2342
'Off3' 'C3'  2131
'Off3' 'C100' 121
'Off3' 'C1'   1231
'Off3' 'C1'   31
```

I would like to aggregate the data based on each offer and client in order to 
get the max amount.

The result would be:

```
Offer Client amount 

'Off1' 'C1'  1000
'Off1' 'C2'  2222
'Off1' 'C3'  10
'Off2' 'C4'  11
'Off2' 'C1'  2342
'Off3' 'C3'  2131
'Off3' 'C100' 121
'Off3' 'C1'   1231
```

- In each offer, a candidate can have several amount of money, so the target is keeping the max value of each candidate in each offer.
- In the case we would like to keep the minimun and maximun offer of each candidate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need aggregate `max` and multiple function with [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Offer', 'Client'], as_index=False)['amount'].max()
print (df1)
    Offer  Client  amount
0  'Off1'    'C1'    1000
1  'Off1'    'C2'    2222
2  'Off1'    'C3'      10
3  'Off2'    'C1'    2342
4  'Off2'    'C4'      11
5  'Off3'    'C1'    1231
6  'Off3'  'C100'     121
7  'Off3'    'C3'    2131

df2 = (df.groupby(['Offer', 'Client'])['amount']
         .agg(['min','max'])
         .add_prefix('amount_')
         .reset_index())
print (df2)
    Offer  Client  amount_min  amount_max
0  'Off1'    'C1'          10        1000
1  'Off1'    'C2'        2222        2222
2  'Off1'    'C3'           0          10
3  'Off2'    'C1'        2342        2342
4  'Off2'    'C4'          11          11
5  'Off3'    'C1'          31        1231
6  'Off3'  'C100'         121         121
7  'Off3'    'C3'        2131        2131
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael I already had the code/way to solve it but without ['amount'], so I wasn't able to get the solution.

Comment: Yes, it should working too, but aggregate all columns. `[]` after groupby is for specify column(s) for aggregate.

Comment: Btw, second solution is what you need?

Comment: both are awesome! @jezrael